# How to show application name in windows tiles in windows phone uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

How to show the application name in the tiles.
  As shown in the figure, i am developing the last application in the screen. For that i need to show the name of the application.
  In PackageManifest file i have added all the images to show the images in the home screen.
 Any help on this highly appreciated.
Thank you.
[image]

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="MMRevamp_2016.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Maalaimalar" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="MMRevamp_2016" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:LockScreen Notification="badge" BadgeLogo="Images\BadgeLogo.png" />
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="Images\Square142x142Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="Images\Square310x310Logo.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
      </uap:VisualElements>
 </Applications>
```

Comment: You just need to set a [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-creating-tiles#configure-the-default-tile).

Comment: in which file, i need to set display name?

Comment: Hi @ChrisW, i have already added display name package.Manifest. I have edited my question. Please check it. Ane, still i am not able to display in the tiles section only, where as in normal menu i am able to see the application name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your Package.appxmanifest and go to Visual Assets, you will see **show name** with check boxes. Check off appropriate box next to your asset.

**See Screenshot for Example**[image]

Comment: thanks bro, it's working absolutely fine. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing XML you can set the branding attribute to "name" as well. E.g like this:

```
<tile>
  <visual>
    <binding template="TileMedium" branding="name">
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```